# GitHub 2FA recovery tokens: is a password still required?

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication

When setting up 2-factor authentication on GitHub, it generates recovery codes which you're supposed to store somewhere. My question is: if someone else gets access to those codes, do they have access to my account - or do they still need my password? I.e. are the recovery codes just a substitute for the code that would otherwise be sent by SMS?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lost-your-2fa-credentials/

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth - it's still ambiguous to me though, since I haven't set up 2FA yet. It says _At the bottom of the 2FA dialog_ - does that dialog only appear _after_ you enter your password?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I just watched a friend signing in. It looks like, indeed, that dialog only shows up after you enter your password. So the saved tokens are a substitute for the 2Fa token that would be sent to your phone. If you added an answer to that effect I'd accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of two-factor authentication is that it adds the second layer of protection. You use not only the password but also the second factor - in your case it is an OTP. Recovery codes have the same functionality with the OTP, so they will be accepted only when the password is valid.